# php ini class cannot see whats going wrong

Tags: php, class, ini

im trying to create a php class that will transform an ini in to an array ie:

example.ini...

```
[helloworld]
testing=1234
```

the array should look like:

```
array {
    "helloworld" = array {
        "testing" = "1234"
    }
}
```

my code fo far is this:

```
<?php
    require_once "UseFullFunctions.inc.php";

    class INI {
        protected $Keys = array();
        protected $Values = array();

        public function __construct($FileName) {
            if (!file_exists($FileName)){
                throwException('File not found',$FileName);
            }
            $File = fopen($FileName, 'r');
            $isIn = "";
            while (($line = fgets($File)) !== false) {
                if(!startswith($line,'#')){  // checks if the line is a comment
                    if(startswith($line,'[')){
                        $isIn = trim($line,'[]');
                        $this->Keys[$isIn] = '';
                        $this->Values[$isIn] = array();
                    } else {
                        if ($isIn != ""){
                            $vars = explode("=",$line);
                            $this->Values[$isIn][$vars[0]] = $vars[1];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            var_dump($this->Values);
            if (!feof($File)) {
                echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
            }
            fclose($File);
        }
        public function getValues() {
            return $this->Values;
        }
    }
?>
```

the other functions(starts with, throwexception) ive already tested and work fine but it still returns a blank array i think its stuffing up just after it checks if the line is a comment but it doesnt come up with an error messages so i cant be sure

just incase here is my starts with code:

```
function throwException($message = null,$code = null) {
    throw new Exception($message,$code);
}

function startsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    return !strncmp($haystack, $needle, strlen($needle));
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using `parse_ini_file` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `parse_ini_file`

https://www.php.net/parse_ini_file

Comment: didn't even know this function existed :(

Comment: Not a PHP function, however take a look at `Zend\Config\Writer\Ini` a Zend Framework component/class. http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.config.writer.html#zend-config-writer-ini

Comment: i wonder what is wrong with my code anyway just out of curiousity